# Default style for all control on Android

Tags: android, styles, android-styles

Is there any method to set the **default style for group of control** of **android** like if i set color for **checkboxes** and also for **edittext** then it applies like in css

In my app i'm `enabling` and `disabling` some control conditionally so i want to change their color can i create a style that change color for all control without applying to each and specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of such thing in Android but you can create a custom background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<gradient android:angle="1dp"
    android:centerColor="@color/sky_blue" 
    android:endColor="@color/white"
    android:startColor="@color/white" />
```

Declare this file as say `backgrnd.xml` in `drawable` folder and when you want to give background to any view just use: `android:background="@drawable/backgrnd"`

Each view will then have same background like this.

Comment: no my question is not that i know i can do this but what you will do if you have many many controls and a number of them are created dynamically need some solution like done in css applying input {}

Comment: Sorry bro!! I don't know if any such thing is available.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the class [**`ColorStateList`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)